# Copper bond wires on a Component

Tags: wirebonding

We must move from WM8731SEFL to WM8731CSEFL, as the original part is obsolete.

I am advised the only difference is the "introduction of copper bond wires".

> Order Code WM8731LSEFL and WM8731LSELF/R changed to WM8731CLSEFL and WM8731CLSEFL/R to reflect change to copper wire bonding.

What is a copper bond wire?  Does it refer to the interconnects, the solder pads or something else?  Could the change affect RF emissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bond wires connect the external pads to the chip die itself. Traditionally they're gold. Presumably some new manufacturing technique allows the use of cheaper copper. I doubt this will be externally detectable; maybe it makes some difference to the expected lifetime and corrosion resistance of the chip.

Comment: Thanks, so most likely RF emissions remain unchanged?

Comment: I would assume so - the wires are tiny.